# Python, assigning values right way in lambda function

Tags: python, lambda, tkinter

I am trying to make a buttons that prints values what i assing to them.
In my mind all buttons should print same values on their text value. Instead they all print "4". What is the wright way to solve this?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def printFunc(text):
    print(text)

list=[0,1,2,3,4]

for i in list:

    w = Button(root, text=list[i],command=lambda: printFunc(list[i])).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to provide a default value at the moment then lambda is constructed

```
from Tkinter import *


root = Tk()

def printFunc(text):
    print(text)

lst=[0,1,2,3,4]

for i in lst:

    w = Button(root, text=lst[i],command=lambda x=lst[i]: printFunc(x)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: wow, thank you so much for your help :D <3

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common beginners problem, because you don't understand how `lambda` works. The solution is to use `functools.partial` instead of lambda.

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

root = Tk()

def printFunc(text):
    print(text)

list=[0,1,2,3,4]

for i in list:
    w = Button(root, text=list[i],command=partial(printFunc, list[i]))
    w.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Also, always put the `pack()` on a new line, so that you avoid another very common beginners problem.

Comment: thank you for the reply! i understand what you mean, i will be careful next time :)